Filtering variables by type does not work on my vscode debug section
In the docs of the current version of VS Code, it says that typing on the variable section on the debug and in other sections of the sidebar, like the file explorer, will filter the vars or files that match that text, but that does not work for me I rechecked the docs to condiment is a nee change, but they confirm that that the way it works
Here are the docs
https://code.visualstudio.com/Docs/editor/debugging#_data-inspection

The image is what I need to fix, in my case, that does not happen

I tried to move all the workbench.list... Setting the preference JSON does not affect the functionality. I also use the workbench setting for search behavior on the settings tab
